# Identificar checkbox al darle clic

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, materialize

Estoy generando una estructura dinámicamente, que obtengo a partir de un json. Tiene la función que al darle clic en el nombre del usuario mostrara otro card en el que tengo 3 checkbox.

El problema que tengo es que al obtener el id y valor de cada checkbox, no importando cual seleccione, solo obtiene el valor del primer checkbox generado.

Si pueden ayudarme para que se identifique correctamente el id y valor de cada checkbox, muchas gracias.

Link Jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/raintrooper/m8tovqbz/

```js
var json = [{
  "Usuario": "Usuario1",
  "Instalado": false,
  "Project": false,
  "Visio": false,
  "Activo": true,
  "Ruta": "https://imgur.com/a/n2EX901",
  "Selector": "UsuarioUno"
}, {
  "Usuario": "Usuario2",
  "Instalado": false,
  "Project": false,
  "Visio": false,
  "Activo": true,
  "Ruta": "https://imgur.com/a/n2EX901",
  "Selector": "Usuario2"
}, {
  "Usuario": "Usuario3",
  "Instalado": false,
  "Project": false,
  "Visio": false,
  "Activo": true,
  "Ruta": "https://imgur.com/a/n2EX901",
  "Selector": "Usuario3"
}];




$('#btnBuscar').click(function() {
  var Usuario = '';
  var Html = '';
  $.each(json, function(i, item) {
    Html += '<div class="col s4">' +
      '<div class="card">' +
      '    <div class="card-image waves-effect waves-block waves-light">' +
      '       <img class="activator" src="' + item.Ruta + '">' +
      '    </div>' +
      '    <ul class="card-action-buttons">' +
      '        <li><a class="btn-floating waves-effect waves-light green accent-4"><i class="mdi-av-repeat">' +
      '        </i></a></li>' +
      '        <li><a class="btn-floating waves-effect waves-light red accent-2"><i class="mdi-action-favorite">' +
      '        </i></a></li>' +
      '        <li><a class="btn-floating waves-effect waves-light light-blue"><i class="mdi-action-info activator">' +
      '        </i></a></li>' +
      '    </ul>' +
      '    <div class="card-content">' +
      '        <span class="card-title activator grey-text text-darken-4">' + item.Usuario + '<i class="material-icons right">more_vert</i></span>' +
      '        <p>' +
      '            <a href="#">This is a link</a></p>' +
      '    </div>' +
      '    <div class="card-reveal">' +
      '        <span class="card-title grey-text text-darken-4">Card Title<i class="material-icons right">close</i></span>' +
      '        <p>' +
      '            Here is some more information about this product that is only revealed once clicked' +
      '            on.</p>' +

      '<p>' +
      ' <input type="checkbox" id="office-' + item.Selector + '" class="lnkOffice" />' +
      '  <label for="office-' + item.Selector + '">Office 365</label>' +
      '</p>' +
      '<p>' +
      ' <input type="checkbox" id="visio-' + item.Selector + '" class="lnkVisio" />' +
      '  <label for="visio-' + item.Selector + '">Visio</label>' +
      '</p>' +
      '<p>' +
      ' <input type="checkbox" id="project-' + item.Selector + '" class="lnkProject" />' +
      '  <label for="project-' + item.Selector + '">Project</label>' +
      '</p>' +

      '   </div>' +
      '   </div>' +
      '</div>';
  });
  $("#Estructura").append(Html);

  $('.lnkOffice').click(function() {
    //                        $('input').unbind()
    var idOffice = $("input:checkbox.lnkOffice").attr("id");
    console.log(idOffice);
    var check = $('#' + idOffice).prop('checked');
    console.log(check);
  });
  $('.lnkVisio').click(function() {
    //                        $('input').unbind()
    var idVisio = $("input:checkbox.lnkVisio").attr("id");
    console.log(idVisio);
    var check = $('#' + idVisio).prop('checked');
    console.log(check);
  });
  $('.lnkProject').click(function() {
    //                        $('input').unbind()
    var idProject = $("input:checkbox.lnkProject").attr("id");
    console.log(idProject);
    var check = $('#' + idProject).prop('checked');
    console.log(check);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.97.6/css/materialize.min.css" media="screen,projection"></link>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.97.6/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
<div class="form-group">
  <a id="btnBuscar" class="btn waves-effect waves-light light-blue darken-4" type="button" value="Buscar" style="width: 100%; margin-top: 10px;" />Buscar</a>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div id="Estructura">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solo tienes que cambiar tus selectores por `this`.  La forma correcta seria asi:

```js
var json = [{
  "Usuario": "Usuario1",
  "Instalado": false,
  "Project": false,
  "Visio": false,
  "Activo": true,
  "Ruta": "https://imgur.com/a/n2EX901",
  "Selector": "UsuarioUno"
}, {
  "Usuario": "Usuario2",
  "Instalado": false,
  "Project": false,
  "Visio": false,
  "Activo": true,
  "Ruta": "https://imgur.com/a/n2EX901",
  "Selector": "Usuario2"
}, {
  "Usuario": "Usuario3",
  "Instalado": false,
  "Project": false,
  "Visio": false,
  "Activo": true,
  "Ruta": "https://imgur.com/a/n2EX901",
  "Selector": "Usuario3"
}];

$('#btnBuscar').click(function() {
  var Usuario = '';
  var Html = '';
  $.each(json, function(i, item) {
    Html += '<div class="col s4">' +
      '<div class="card">' +
      '    <div class="card-image waves-effect waves-block waves-light">' +
      '       <img class="activator" src="' + item.Ruta + '">' +
      '    </div>' +
      '    <ul class="card-action-buttons">' +
      '        <li><a class="btn-floating waves-effect waves-light green accent-4"><i class="mdi-av-repeat">' +
      '        </i></a></li>' +
      '        <li><a class="btn-floating waves-effect waves-light red accent-2"><i class="mdi-action-favorite">' +
      '        </i></a></li>' +
      '        <li><a class="btn-floating waves-effect waves-light light-blue"><i class="mdi-action-info activator">' +
      '        </i></a></li>' +
      '    </ul>' +
      '    <div class="card-content">' +
      '        <span class="card-title activator grey-text text-darken-4">' + item.Usuario + '<i class="material-icons right">more_vert</i></span>' +
      '        <p>' +
      '            <a href="#">This is a link</a></p>' +
      '    </div>' +
      '    <div class="card-reveal">' +
      '        <span class="card-title grey-text text-darken-4">Card Title<i class="material-icons right">close</i></span>' +
      '        <p>' +
      '            Here is some more information about this product that is only revealed once clicked' +
      '            on.</p>' +

      '<p>' +
      ' <input type="checkbox" id="office-' + item.Selector + '" class="lnkOffice" />' +
      '  <label for="office-' + item.Selector + '">Office 365</label>' +
      '</p>' +
      '<p>' +
      ' <input type="checkbox" id="visio-' + item.Selector + '" class="lnkVisio" />' +
      '  <label for="visio-' + item.Selector + '">Visio</label>' +
      '</p>' +
      '<p>' +
      ' <input type="checkbox" id="project-' + item.Selector + '" class="lnkProject" />' +
      '  <label for="project-' + item.Selector + '">Project</label>' +
      '</p>' +

      '   </div>' +
      '   </div>' +
      '</div>';
  });
  $("#Estructura").append(Html);

  $('.lnkOffice').click(function() {
    //                        $('input').unbind()
    var idOffice = $(this).attr("id");
    console.log(idOffice);
    var check = $('#' + idOffice).prop('checked');
    console.log(check);
  });
  $('.lnkVisio').click(function() {
    //                        $('input').unbind()
    var idVisio = $(this).attr("id");
    console.log(idVisio);
    var check = $('#' + idVisio).prop('checked');
    console.log(check);
  });
  $('.lnkProject').click(function() {
    //                        $('input').unbind()
    var idProject = $(this).attr("id");
    console.log(idProject);
    var check = $('#' + idProject).prop('checked');
    console.log(check);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.97.6/css/materialize.min.css" media="screen,projection"></link>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.97.6/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
<div class="form-group">
  <a id="btnBuscar" class="btn waves-effect waves-light light-blue darken-4" type="button" value="Buscar" style="width: 100%; margin-top: 10px;" />Buscar</a>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div id="Estructura">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Solo te muestra el primero porque no le estás indicando que te muestre al que le hagas click, para eso tienes que usar la palabra this,

por ejemplo:

```
 $('.lnkOffice').click(function() {
     //                        $('input').unbind()
     var idOffice = $("input:checkbox.lnkOffice").attr("id");
     console.log(idOffice);
     var check = $('#' + idOffice).prop('checked');
     console.log(check);
  });
```

debe ser cambiado por algo así:

```
 $('.lnkOffice').click(function() {
     //                        $('input').unbind()
     var idOffice = this.attr("id");
     console.log(idOffice);
     var check = $('#' + idOffice).prop('checked');
     console.log(check);
});
```

No lo he probado, solo lo vi y lo escribí a ojo así que puede que tenga sus errores pero el problema es ese.

`$('.class')` devuelve un `array` de objetos, al usar `this` le estás diciendo que solo seleccione al que se le hizo click...

Answer (score 0):

```js
//Seleccionas todos los elementos con clase test
var divs = document.getElementsByClassName("test");
    
    //Recorres la lista de elementos seleccionados
    for (var i=0; i< divs.length; i++) {
        //Añades un evento a cada elemento
        divs[i].addEventListener("click",function(event) {
           //Aquí la función que se ejecutará cuando se dispare el evento
           alert("El id es: " + event.target.id); //En este caso alertaremos el id del cliqueado
        });
    }
```

```html
<p class="test"><input type="checkbox" id="project1"/><label>Project1</label> </p>
<p class="test"><input type="checkbox" id="project2"/><label >Project2</label> </p>
```